# bazel Failed to create temporary file

Tags: c++, bazel

I have download the git repo containing the [c++ tutorial](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cpp.html) for bazel and I am trying to compile the examples.
When performing the command `bazel build //main:hello-world`, I get the following error:

```
ccache: error: Failed to create temporary file for /home/username/.ccache/tmp/tmp.cpp_stderr: Read-only file system
```

Thus I tried several actions: `sudo bazel`, change permission to /.ccache/tmp/ folder but none has worked. How can I get ride of this error ?

I work on fedora27.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Bazel, ccache, and sandboxing to work together (ccache read only filesystem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370202/how-to-get-bazel-ccache-and-sandboxing-to-work-together-ccache-read-only-file)

Comment: Why do you try to use ccache and Bazel at the same time? You'll use redundant caches, won't you?

Answer (score 9):

The reason for this error is that ccache is used and requires write access ~/.ccache.
See in Ondrej's comment to: [Bazel building C++ sample with ccache fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858954/bazel-building-c-sample-with-ccache-fails)

Using --sandbox_writable_path ~/.ccache fixes the issue without disabling the sandbox feature.

Answer (score 3):

Solved using the option `--strategy=CppCompile=standalone` :

```
bazel build //main:hello-world --strategy=CppCompile=standalone
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this change will disable sand-boxing, which might not be what you actually want...