# How to get Bazel, ccache, and sandboxing to work together (ccache read only filesystem)

Tags: bazel, ccache

I'm attempting to build a C++ application on Fedora 28 using Bazel 0.16.1 installed via copr and ccache 3.4.2 installed via DNF. I'm using the default cc_binary and cc_library rules. When I run the bazel build command, ccache errors out with:

```
ccache: error: Failed to create temporary file for /home/mwalker/.ccache/tmp/time.stdout: Read-only file system
```

I can see when I build with `--verbose_failures --sandbox_debug` that we're not mounting the ccache tmp directory r/w.

So, how do I get bazel to mount my ccache directory r/w, or how do I tell ccache through bazel where the correct cache directory for my workspace resides?

<s>When I run the same command on Ubuntu 18.04 it succeeds, so this leads me to believe that ccache is supported in some way.</s>

It looks like part of my problem is that ccache installed its compiler driver as gcc. E.g. `which gcc -> /usr/lib64/ccache/gcc`. Where on Ubuntu ccache must be explicitly invoked, and the default toolchain is not calling it.

Comment: Doc issue to have ccache usage documented in Bazel docs, https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/12124

Answer (score 11):

You can add existing directories to the sandbox with [`--sandbox_writable_path=<path>`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html)[1].

---

[1] https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html

Comment: Copy and paste: `bazel build --sandbox_writable_path=$HOME/.ccache`

Comment: add this to your ~/.bazelrc and never think about it again

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem in Fedora 29, in my case was solved by exporting the next environment variables:

```
export CC="/usr/bin/gcc"
export CXX="/usr/bin/g++"
```

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1322#issuecomment-226919588

Comment: This looks like a workaround, it causes Bazel not to use ccache.